# Issue with ejabberd file permissions

Tags: ejabberd

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 desktop. I installed ejabberd. I'm trying to edit the /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg file, but get 'permission denied' even though my id is in both the root and ejabberd user groups.

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance for any help with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command on terminal to edit ejabberd.cfg file,

```
sudo gedit /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg
```

After editing don't forget to save that file.